# Compare two files and get the matching line result from 2nd file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, comm

I have two files ,

```
$cat file_1.txt
95335df46cfdb345c0214296e0043c00,NA
a0af947a85e6895dab70eaec136cfed2,NA

$cat file_2.txt
77f673137c17b4b0405d13060e9715a3,5,X,Y
874d51610c15975c82c081aba0b096c3,5,A,M
95335df46cfdb345c0214296e0043c00,5,M,N
```

I'm comparing `first` field from "file_1.txt" against `first` field against `"file_2.txt"`. If there is `'hash'` any match , get the complete matching line from `"file_2.txt"`.

Matched Line : ( From `file_2.txt` )

```
95335df46cfdb345c0214296e0043c00,5,M,N
```

I tried using `awk`, But not getting any results.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} ($1) in a' file_1.txt file_2.txt
```

Am i making any mistake here ? Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a' file_1.txt file_2.txt
95335df46cfdb345c0214296e0043c00,5,M,N
```

You missed specifying that `,` is delimiter to use

Comment: Ah ! Snap. Sorry , I missed the delimited here. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Using `join` command:

```
join -t',' -o2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4 <(sort file_1.txt) <(sort file_2.txt)
```

The output:

```
95335df46cfdb345c0214296e0043c00,5,M,N
```

---

- `-t','` - input/output field separator